# How do I prevent source() R code being included more than once?

Tags: r, include-guards

I have lots of R source files. For example, in both `A.R` and `C.R` files, `B.R` is loaded via `source()`. Now I'd like to use the functions in both `A.R` and `C.R`, how can I avoid sourcing `B.R` repeatedly? Is there any include guard mechanisms similar in C/C++?

Comment: The answer is almost certainly to put `B.R` in a package, and then to load it with the `library()` function.

Comment: well, to make it a package is too overkilled. No simpler way?

Comment: If there is no obvious way to do that, I am actually thinking about a similar solution to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518584/is-there-any-mechanism-in-shell-script-alike-include-guard-in-c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If B.R already has a function or data set in it with a rather unique name, you could use it as a guard. Otherwise, just define one:

B.R

```
B_is_loaded <- TRUE
# The normal B stuff
```

A.R:

```
if(!exists("B_is_loaded")) source("B.R")
# Now you can call the stuff in B
```